# Сессия перезаписывает значения php

Tags: php, laravel, сессия

Я получаю данные с фронта на php, мне нужно, что бы они сохранялись в сессию и перезаписывались, только если эти значения одинаковые. Но перезаписываются все данные.
Должен быть массив вида

```
array:1 [
  "industry" => "Administration & Support Services",
  "availability" => "Immediate"
];
```

если приходит значение industry к примеру новое, то должно перезаписаться только оно. Но весь массив перезаписывается при каждом новом запросе, и там всегда одно значение.
Вот код php

```
public function filterApplicants($search, $request, $withMatch)
  {

    $_SESSION['filters'][$request->filter_type] = $request->filter_value;
    dd($_SESSION['filters']);
    $searchResult = $search->handle(session('data_applicant_search'), $withMatch, $_SESSION['filters']);

    if (!$request->get('page')) {
      $paginateApplicants = $this->customPagination($searchResult, 1, false);
    } else {
      $paginateApplicants = $this->customPagination($searchResult, $request->get('page'), false);
    }

    return $paginateApplicants;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы работать с сессией php, ее нужно для начала стартовать
`session_start()`

Для работы с сессией Laravel я бы посоветовал документацию https://laravel.ru/docs/v5/session

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).